# connecting sql server 2008 r2 to netbeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

i  want to create  an java application which has to create a database and later access it.
My problem is that i am not able to connect sql server 2008 r2 database driver on to the netbeans.i have sql server 2008 r2 installed on my system.please suggest me the step by step procedure to establish the connection

Answer (score 1):

Firstly u need to download Microsoft driver for jdbc http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774 for smoother database connectivity.
Install it in your C: drive/follow the instruction in default.html file in the installation folder.
To use this in NetBeans, right click on  add jar library from the Library node  of your project and navigate to the installation path to add sqljdbc.jar for jdk5 and below or sqljdbc4.jar 
 for otherwise.Look up the help file for how to make connection and getDriverManager parameters.It gets more fun when using it an enterprise app.Let me know if you need anymore help